# why this shader variable doesn't change?(dx12, hlsl)

Tags: shader, hlsl, directx-12, shadow-mapping

I'm working with dx12 and hlsl, and this specific root constant seems doesn't change or doesn't work for index.

this is hlsl code

```
#include "LightUtil.hlsli"

cbuffer cbCameraInfo : register(b1)
{
    matrix gmtxViewProj : packoffset(c0);
    float3 cameraPos : packoffset(c4);
    
    //size : 19
};

cbuffer cbLightInfo : register(b2)
{
    int nLights : packoffset(c0);
    int nShadowIndex : packoffset(c4); // - this is the constant
}

cbuffer cbShadowInfo : register(b3)
{
    matrix gmtxShadowTransform[3];
    matrix gmtxLightViewProj[3];
    matrix gmtxCascadedViewProj[3];
    float3 ShadowCameraPos;
}

Texture2D gShadowMap[3] : register(t0);
Texture2D gTextureMaps[6] : register(t3);

struct INSTANCED_GAMEOBJECT_INFO
{
    matrix m_mtxGameObject;
    int m_nTextrueIndex;
};
StructuredBuffer<INSTANCED_GAMEOBJECT_INFO> gGameObjectInfos : register(t0, space1);

StructuredBuffer<LIGHT_INFO> light : register(t1, space1);

SamplerState gsamPointWrap : register(s0);
SamplerState gsamPointClamp : register(s1);
SamplerState gsamLinearWrap : register(s2);
SamplerState gsamLinearClamp : register(s3);
SamplerState gsamAnisotropicWrap : register(s4);
SamplerState gsamAnisotropicClamp : register(s5);
SamplerComparisonState gsamShadow : register(s6);
```

and when I use nShadowIndex like this

```
#include "Common.hlsli"

struct VertexIn
{
    float3 PosL : POSITION;
};

struct VertexOut
{
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
};

VertexOut VS(VertexIn vin)
{
    VertexOut vout = (VertexOut) 0.0f;
    
    // Transform to world space.
    float4 posW = mul(float4(vin.PosL, 1.0f), gmtxWorld);
    // Transform to homogeneous clip space.
    
    vout.PosH = mul(posW, gmtxLightViewProj[nShadowIndex]);
    
    return vout;
}

// This is only used for alpha cut out geometry, so that shadows 
// show up correctly.  Geometry that does not need to sample a
// texture can use a NULL pixel shader for depth pass.
void PS(VertexOut pin)
{
    // Fetch the material data.
    MATERIAL matData = material;
    float4 diffuseAlbedo = matData.DiffuseAlbedo;
}
```

this shader always returns same result because of nShadowIndex always fixed to 0.

and this is how i set variables. (there's many other vars, but not that important for this)
as you see, what i'm trying to do is cascaded shadow map.

```
void CShadowShader::UpdateShaderVariables(ID3D12GraphicsCommandList* pd3dCommandList, XMFLOAT3 xmf3TargetPos, float fBoundary, int nShadowIndex)
{
    XMVECTOR lightPos = XMLoadFloat3(&m_pLight->GetPosition());
    XMVECTOR TargetPos = XMLoadFloat3(&xmf3TargetPos);
    XMVECTOR lightUp = XMLoadFloat3(&m_pLight->GetUp());

    XMVECTOR lightDir = XMVectorSubtract(lightPos, TargetPos);
    float lightLength = XMVector3Length(lightDir).m128_f32[0];

    XMMATRIX lightView = XMMatrixLookAtLH(lightPos, TargetPos, lightUp);

    // Transform bounding sphere to light space.
    XMFLOAT3 xmf3CenterLS;
    XMStoreFloat3(&xmf3CenterLS, XMVector3TransformCoord(XMLoadFloat3(&xmf3TargetPos), lightView));

    // Ortho frustum in light space encloses scene.
    float l = xmf3CenterLS.x - fBoundary;
    float b = xmf3CenterLS.y - fBoundary;
    float n = xmf3CenterLS.z - fBoundary;
    float r = xmf3CenterLS.x + fBoundary;
    float t = xmf3CenterLS.y + fBoundary;
    float f = xmf3CenterLS.z + fBoundary;

    XMMATRIX lightProj;
    lightProj = XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH(l, r, b, t, n, f);

    // Transform NDC space [-1,+1]^2 to texture space [0,1]^2
    XMMATRIX T(
        0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    XMMATRIX S = lightView * lightProj;

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_xmf4x4LightViewProj[nShadowIndex], XMMatrixTranspose(S));

    S = S * T;

    XMStoreFloat4x4(&m_xmf4x4ShadowTransform[nShadowIndex], XMMatrixTranspose(S));

    CB_SHADOW cbShadow{ m_xmf4x4ShadowTransform, m_xmf4x4LightViewProj, m_pLight->GetPosition(), m_xmf4x4CascadedViewProj};

    m_ubShadowCB->CopyData(0, cbShadow);
    pd3dCommandList->SetGraphicsRootConstantBufferView(3, m_ubShadowCB->Resource()->GetGPUVirtualAddress());
    pd3dCommandList->SetGraphicsRoot32BitConstants(2, 1, &nShadowIndex, 1);
}
```

here's graphics root signature. there's few korean comment. but not important

```
ID3D12RootSignature* CScene::CreateGraphicsRootSignature(ID3D12Device* pd3dDevice)
{
    ID3D12RootSignature* pd3dGraphicsRootSignature = NULL;
    CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER pd3dRootParameters[8];

    //32비트 루트 상수
    pd3dRootParameters[0].InitAsConstants(28, 0, 0, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);
    pd3dRootParameters[1].InitAsConstants(19, 1, 0, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);
    pd3dRootParameters[2].InitAsConstants(2, 2, 0, D3D12_SHADER_VISIBILITY_ALL);

    //UploadBuffer 클래스를 이용하여 업로드
    pd3dRootParameters[3].InitAsConstantBufferView(3);

    //구조화 된 버퍼, stdafx.h의 CreateBufferResource 함수 이용해 업로드
    pd3dRootParameters[4].InitAsShaderResourceView(0, 1);
    pd3dRootParameters[5].InitAsShaderResourceView(1, 1);

    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE shadowMapRange(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 3, 0, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND); // 3개, 0 ~ 2
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE texRange(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_SRV, 6, 3, 0, D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_OFFSET_APPEND); // 6개, 3 ~ 8

    //디스크립터 테이블 이용하여 업로드
    pd3dRootParameters[6].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &shadowMapRange); //쉐도우 맵 - 6, 7, 8
    pd3dRootParameters[7].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &texRange); //텍스쳐 배열 - 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

    auto staticSamplers = GetStaticSamplers();

    CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC d3dRootSignatureDesc(_countof(pd3dRootParameters), pd3dRootParameters, (UINT)staticSamplers.size(), staticSamplers.data(), D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);

    ID3DBlob* pd3dSignatureBlob = NULL;
    ID3DBlob* pd3dErrorBlob = NULL;
    auto tmp = ::D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&d3dRootSignatureDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &pd3dSignatureBlob, &pd3dErrorBlob);

    if (pd3dErrorBlob != NULL)
    {
        auto tmp = (char*)pd3dErrorBlob->GetBufferPointer();
        std::string p = tmp;
        p.c_str();
    }

    pd3dDevice->CreateRootSignature(0, pd3dSignatureBlob->GetBufferPointer(), pd3dSignatureBlob->GetBufferSize(), __uuidof(ID3D12RootSignature), (void**)&pd3dGraphicsRootSignature);

    if (pd3dSignatureBlob)
        pd3dSignatureBlob->Release();

    if (pd3dErrorBlob)
        pd3dErrorBlob->Release();

    return(pd3dGraphicsRootSignature);
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition of your root signature? When do you set it?

Comment: i'll update about that. wait a sec plz

Comment: I set this root signature far before UpdateShaderVariables. so there's no worry about that

Comment: here's full code : https://github.com/kcjsend2/3DGP-BulletPhysics/tree/Cascaded-Shadow-Map

Comment: Are you checking the ``HRESULT`` for failure. For example, do you know if ``CreateRootSignature`` actually succeeded?

Comment: it actually suceeded well. and program runs exactly what i want except that nShadowIndex variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
cbuffer cbLightInfo : register(b2)
{
int nLights : packoffset(c0);
int nShadowIndex : packoffset(c4); // - this is the constant
}
```

try making it:

```
int nLights : packoffset(c0.x);
int nShadowIndex : packoffset(c0.y);
```